# Deactivate date integrity check in Foxit Reader

Tags: date, error-handling, foxit, foxit-reader

Is there any way to deactivate the date integrity check in Foxit Reader? Background is that I am filling a form where I shall enter the date in different formats (sometimes it's YYYY/MM/DD, sometimes it's just YYYY/MM). Each time I enter a date or any other field that is related to that date field I get an error popup that says

> The input string can't be parsed to valid Date and time.

Unfortunately there are 36 rows with 4 columns each that I have to fill. Plus: That error message always occurs twice. So I have to click away 36 * 4 * 2 = 288 error popups.

Does anyone know a way to deactivate that check? Thanks a million...

**Update:**
It's actually even worse. Each time I edit *any* input field on that form this error popup occurs twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out by myself. In <kbd>HOME</kbd> > <kbd>PREFERENCES</kbd> > <kbd>Trust Manager</kbd> I had to uncheck

> Enable JavaScript Actions

Answer (score 2):

The issue here really lies with the PDF file, not the reader. Whoever created the PDF form you are using decided that each date field should have a format check. You can use a PDF editor such as Adobe Acrobat or Foxit PhantomPDF to remove these checks, or you can ask whoever created the file to do so. Changing that setting prevented the checks from working, but won't do anything if, for example, you send the file to someone else.